# Forget the keystore password. How to recover it?

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I am trying to integrate the google plus login in my app So I need SHA 1.

So I am trying to generate through command line using

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v

but it is asking for the keystore password, when I am entering the password( that i use will while signing the apk) It says wrong password.

How to reset that password?

Comment: ALWAYS backup up your keystore and write the passwords down in a safe location.

Comment: That keystore is generated by the Android SDK, and it uses a hardcoded password of `android`. For your own keystore, be sure to back it up and record your passwords in your password manager program (e.g., KeePass).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default password for ~/.android/debug.keystore is android